# client_side_validations does not work with simple_nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

The client side validations gem is working fine with simple_form and formatastic but if i use simple_nested_form it is not working. any solution would be helpful or is there any workaround to get client side validtions working on simple_nested_form?

Comment: Some help is given here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/wiki/Integrating-with-client_side_validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no adapter currently written for simple_nested_form. For every form builder out there ClientSideValidations needs to be customized. This became very difficult to maintain in the core gem so I have since split it into different adapters. I outline this here: http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/01/22/client-side-validations-goes-modular.html

Unfortunately my time has been very limited over the past few months and I haven't been able to get much work done on completing this effort.

Comment: Thank alot for the answer. :) looking fwd to see the problem getting completely resolved.